# Python multi-threading with daemon threads

Tags: python, multithreading, daemon

For a personal purpose, I'm trying to set a framework of different tools.

For that, I need to create the main thread as a daemon thread. This daemon thread is launched in command line by typing `framework` (alias for `python framework.py`).

This thread is supposed to create a child thread which is a GUI interface (metasploit-alike). In that GUI interface, you can navigate through modules using `use <module>` command and then run it in background with `run`. Each module you want to run is a daemon thread created by the main daemon thread.

So, those tools are running in background and are taking some time (days). This is why, you may leave the GUI interface and the main daemon thread is still handling the child daemon threads used for running tools.

I've tried something like this but the child thread (created by the main daemon thread) supposed to launch the GUI interface does not use *stdout* for the printed stuffs, therefore I do not have any graphic interface. Do you know if there is any way to fix it quite easily without using any library (TKinter, QThread, ...) ?

**TO SUM UP**

I have a main daemon thread handling either a thread for a graphic interface and daemon threads for running tools in background. It also handles communication between graphic interface and daemon threads for tools (e.g. the user can use `kill` command so that the main daemon thread kills the child daemon threads for tools).

**END OF SUM UP**

This is my Thread module :

```
class IOThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, inQueue, outQueue, fct, fctParam=None, daemon=True):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.inQueue = inQueue
        self.outQueue = outQueue
        self.fct = fct
        self.fctParam = fctParam
        # Set properties and start thread
        self.daemon = daemon
        self.start()

    def run(self):

        while True:

            #Get from queue job
            inObj = self.inQueue.get()
            if self.fctParam is None:
                outObj = self.fct (inObj)
            else:
                outObj = self.fct (inObj, self.fctParam)

            if self.outQueue is not None:
                self.outQueue.put(outObj)

            self.inQueue.task_done()

# To be used to launch the GUI from the main daemon thread
def launchGUI(function):
    try:
        inQueue = Queue()
        inQueue.put(None)

        IOThread(inQueue, None, function, daemon=False)

    except TypeError as e: print(e)
```

And this is how I launch the main daemon thread supposed to create and launch my GUI thread :

```
# create the graphic interface
def openGUI():
    # prints some stuffs for the graphic interface

# create the graphic thread
def mainloop():
    try: launchGUI(openGUI)
    except Exception as e: print(e)

# starts in daemon and launch the graphic thread
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with daemon.DaemonContext():
        mainloop()
```